# Parse express server side login using express-session

Tags: parse-platform

I'm using parse on node. I have an express app, and a JS browser app, that is hosted off the express server.

At the moment the app has it's own login. It logs the user in on the client, and the client remains logged in.

I want to be able to log the client in via an express route /login. When they log in via this route, i want to log them in on the client side.

I have poured over documentation on this but I have struggled to find any real examples of how this is all done.

Here is some code i have found:

```
    var cookieSession = require('cookie-session'),

        // I added this require as it seems the code is using it;
        session = require('express-session');



    app.use(cookieSession({
      name: COOKIE_NAME,
      secret: "SECRET_SIGNING_KEY",
      maxAge: 15724800000
    }));
    //
    // This will add req.user if they are logged in;
    //
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
          url: 'http://localhost:1337/parse/users/me',
          headers: {
            'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'myAppId',
            'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'myRestAPIKey',
            'X-Parse-Session-Token': req.session.token
          }
        }).then(function (userData) {
            req.user = Parse.Object.fromJSON(userData.data);
            next();
        }).then(null, function () {
            return res.redirect('/login');
        });
    });
 //
 // login route;
 //
 app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    Parse.User.logIn(req.body.username, req.body.password).then(function(user) {
      req.session.user = user;
      req.session.token = user.getSessionToken();
      res.redirect('/');
    }, function(error) {
      req.session = null;
      res.render('login', { flash: error.message });
    });
  });
  //
  // and logout.
  //
  app.post('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.session = null;
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

This looks pretty good, but this won't add a session on the client? How do parse the server login down to the client; Do i pass the session Token and use it on the client?

```
//
// If i call this code in the browser, i want the logged in user;
//
var current_user = Parse.User.current();
```

I have been unable to find any real code on-line that demonstrates all of this in the best-practice manner.

Is this the 'best practice' known solution or is there a better way of doing this?